# writing C language with vscode on Macbook

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Does it work for Mac as well? Or is this library only for Windows?

Comment: Are you asking because you're having problems with vscode saying that `<stdio.h>` can't be found on your Mac?

Comment: `<stdio.h>` is the most common, the most standard, the most popular, the most important header file in all of C.  You can't write "Hello, world!" without `<stdio.h>`.  If you have a compiler or IDE that claims to be for C, but it is saying that there's some problem with`<stdio.h>`, then it is **not** actually a compiler or IDE for C, after all.  (And if you have to do some tricky or nondefault explicit configuration to teach your IDE how to properly handle `<stdio.h>`, that's no excuse.)

Comment: You should be asking such a question after you have actually tried that. If it didn't work for you, you should have described what and how.

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for comment. Problems is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `stdio.h` (along with several others such as `stdlib.h`, `string.h`, and others) are part of the C standard library. They are available on **all** standard conforming implementations/platforms, including MacOS, Windows, Linux, and many more.